# 3 x 3 images in table format with vertical caption on left has alignment and scaling issues

Tags: spacing, alignment

I am using overleaf and IEEE conference template which is a two column format. I am trying to show 3 x 3 images. After searching on internet, I got the following code almost working but it has alignment and scaling issues. 1) The image labels on the left which are rotated should align with bottom of cell. 2) I would like the image to be a little more bigger. What is causing the issue and how can I fix them?
Here is my code (the usepackage part is not minimal but the core code is minimal):
I get the attached image.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if 
                                                          % you want to use the \thanks command

\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed to meet printer requirements.

%In case you encounter the following error:
%Error 1010 The PDF file may be corrupt (unable to open PDF file) OR
%Error 1000 An error occurred while parsing a contents stream. Unable to analyze the PDF file.
%This is a known problem with pdfLaTeX conversion filter. The file cannot be opened with acrobat reader
%Please use one of the alternatives below to circumvent this error by uncommenting one or the other
%\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
%\pdfminorversion=4

% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
%\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
%\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,ragged2e}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}

% For controlling hyphenations
\lefthyphenmin=10
\righthyphenmin=10

% if there are consecutive entries with same author names, ieee style
% replaces the 2nd entry by "--". To change this non-sense behavior,
% set the following 'dashed' flag to false.

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Bla bla blah}
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l  m{15mm}  m{15mm}  m{15mm}  }
         \rothead{Blah blah longer blah} &  
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  & 
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \\
        \rothead{Blah blah longer blah} &  
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        \rothead{Blah blah longer blah} &  
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        \rothead{Blah blah longer blah} &  
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

This code produces the image which is attached.
[image: Layout issues]

Comment: please have a look at the answer below -- I am working with the `article` class of document since I do not have the `IEEE` class

Answer (score 2):

The “wrong” positioning of the rotated labels is due to two factors:

1. `\rothead` in the first place;
2. the `m` columns as a further problem.

Use `\rotatebox` instead. Here I show how to get the same horizontal and vertical space between the images.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if 
                                                          % you want to use the \thanks command

\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed to meet printer requirements.

% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\caption{Bla bla blah}
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\dp\strutbox} % the devious trick!

\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{\quad} ccc @{}}
  \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{10mm}{\raggedright Blah blah longer blah}} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} \\
  \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{10mm}{\raggedright Blah blah longer blah}} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} \\
  \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{10mm}{\raggedright Blah blah longer blah}} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, egreg. The left hand side labels are coming nicely. I still would like to scale the images a tad bit (both in height and width). How can I achieve it?

Comment: @shaileshn Change the width parameter, now at 15mm as in the original

Comment: Thank you, that parameter took care of width and height (I was not aware of its impact).

Answer (score -1):

For the rotation alignment to bottom use option `b` with `rothead`

```
        \rothead[b]{Blah blah longer blah}
```

RESULT

[image]

For bigger images simply change the dimensions of the columns of the table to

```
\begin{tabular}{l  m{0.3\textwidth}  m{0.3\textwidth}  m{0.3\textwidth}  }
```

In terms of `textwidth` rather than absolute rigid/fixed dimensions

RESULT

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if 
% you want to use the \thanks command

%\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed to meet printer requirements.

%In case you encounter the following error:
%Error 1010 The PDF file may be corrupt (unable to open PDF file) OR
%Error 1000 An error occurred while parsing a contents stream. Unable to analyze the PDF file.
%This is a known problem with pdfLaTeX conversion filter. The file cannot be opened with acrobat reader
%Please use one of the alternatives below to circumvent this error by uncommenting one or the other
%\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
%\pdfminorversion=4

% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
%\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
%\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}

% For controlling hyphenations
\lefthyphenmin=10
\righthyphenmin=10

% if there are consecutive entries with same author names, ieee style
% replaces the 2nd entry by "--". To change this non-sense behavior,
% set the following 'dashed' flag to false.

\begin{document}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{table}[t]
        \caption{Bla bla blah}
        \label{wasr_as_is_ir}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l  m{0.3\textwidth}  m{0.3\textwidth}  m{0.3\textwidth}  }
                        \rothead[b]{Blah blah longer blah} &  
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  & 
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \\
            \rothead[b]{Blah blah longer blah} &  
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
            \rothead[b]{Blah blah longer blah} &  
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
            \rothead[b]{Blah blah longer blah} &  
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, ]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]